# "Part of menu-item path is not sub-menu" error in vim config

Tags: macos, vim

I recently started getting this error when I opened vim, and I have no idea why.

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim73/menu.vim:
line  352:
E327: Part of menu-item path is not sub-menu
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I have never edited that file, and don't really understand what's wrong. Here is the part thats causing the error:

```
 349 " define all the submenu entries
 350 let s:idx = 100
 351 for s:name in s:names
 352   exe "an 20.450." . s:idx . ' &Edit.C&olor\ Scheme.' . s:name . " :colors " . s:name . "<CR>"
 353   let s:idx = s:idx + 10
 354 endfor
 355 unlet s:name s:names s:n s:idx
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks! Btw, Im on OS X 10.8 with Vim 7.3

Comment: I would save off the things you care about (`.vimrc`, etc.) and remove/reinstall vim.  Not an idea solution, but sounds like that will be the simplest route.  If you are open to editor suggestions, take a look at [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/).  I used to use `vim` until I was referred to it.  The keyboard commands and features are fantastic (and you can make plugins using Python.  Which is how it should be, simple and quick instead of `vim` specific...)

Comment: I use Sublime Text 3 most of the time, but I use vim for quick changes when I'm already in the command line, or for editing hidden files.

Comment: Adding information like your operating system, vim version etc. to your question could help. Please just choose a tag for your OS.

Comment: I had to format my hard drive so this got fixed as a result, but I did put my OS as a tag, and I specified the version of Vim and OS X in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the script we have:

```
" get NL separated string with file names
let s:n = globpath(&runtimepath, "colors/*.vim")

let s:names = sort(map(split(s:n, "\n"), 'substitute(v:val, "\\c.*[/\\\\:\\]]\\([^/\\\\:]*\\)\\.vim", "\\1", "")'), 1)

" define all the submenu entries
let s:idx = 100
for s:name in s:names
  exe "an 20.450." . s:idx . ' &Edit.C&olor\ Scheme.' . s:name . " :colors " . s:name . "<CR>"
  let s:idx = s:idx + 10
endfor
unlet s:name s:names s:n s:idx
```

Now, if you look at `s:names`, it's iterating over `s:n`, which is the list of all the vim files contained in color directories on the runtimepath. My first step of debugging my issue was to move all my custom color files out of the way, and open vim... bingo, no error message. Now it was just a case of figuring out which color file was causing the error.

Interestingly I had a color file called `blackboard.vim.vim` in my  color files, I guessed this was the offending file, and lo behold it was. Removing the file fixed the problem.